# HOW TO MOVE BITCOIN

Tags: sell-bitcoins

I bought some BTC in 2013 to see what it was all about. I eventually moved the BTC to a paper wallet where it still is. Now, I am thinking that maybe I will sell the BTC, but I have cold feet about how to move the BTC into, say, an exchange. Presumably the exchange has a wallet with an address ? Could someone kindly point me to some instructions ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have private keys in your Bitcoin adress.

1. So first install a bitcoin wallet (a lightweit one is Ok, such as the ordinary android Bitcoin wallet, samuray wallet...).
2. Then import your privkeys to your wallet.
3. Open an account in an exchange (for example Bittrex)
4. The exchange will give you an adress to which you can send your bitcoins from your wallet.
5. You can sell your bitcoins in the exchange.